# Минимизация расстояний от множества точек до плоскости

Tags: математика, геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия

Подскажите что почитать или с помощью какого алгоритма лучше сделать следующую процедуру:
Есть облако точек, нужно поместить плоскость среди них так, чтобы сумма квадратов расстояний от точек до плоскости было минимально?
Куда смотреть? Градиентный спуск, если да, то как его задать, или есть что лучше/проще?

Comment: вам нужна обычная линейная регрессия.

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов Линейная ли? Там же явно нелинейная функция получается.

Answer (score 3):

Ну, как я понимаю, примерно так...

Если плоскость задана как [image: введите сюда описание изображения], то расстояние до нее от точки [image: введите сюда описание изображения] равно (пишу сразу для квадрата)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше все, как в [методе наименьших квадратов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) - нужно нормировать, скажем, принимая a или b или c равным 1, просуммировать все квадраты и приравнять к нулю производные суммы по трем оставшимся переменным. Получим систему уравнений, из которых находятся коэффициенты плоскости.

Конечно, задача **существенно** упрощается, если рассматривать не минимальные расстояния до плоскости, а расстояние, скажем, по вертикали (оси z) - тогда все вырождается в простейшую систему *линейных* уравнений.